# How to make a jQuery Mobile popup appear in full screen of device

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have been trying hard to make a popup appear in full screen in JQM but not able to do it

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/N2UYZ/)

And the code looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id=""> <a href="#sql" id="opendialog" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline" data-transition="pop">Open Dialog</a>

    <div data-role="popup" id="sql" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:100%">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
             <h1>Delete Page?</h1>

        </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
             <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>

            <p>This action cannot be undone.</p> <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
 <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">Delete</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/N2UYZ/1/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- **CSS solution:**

  This will apply to any popup.

  ```
  .ui-popup-container, .ui-popup {
      height: 98%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left:0;
  }
  ```
- **JS solution:**

  Target specific popup.

  ```
  $(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
      $("#sql").popup({
          beforeposition: function () {
              $(this).css({
                  width: window.innerWidth,
                  height: window.innerHeight - 14
              });
          },
          x: 0,
          y: 0
      });
  });
  ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/f76nD/)**

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the default jQuery mobile padding of 15px for popups, and set the popup width to 100%, while not writing hard-coded values, you can do the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="popup" id="sql" data-dismissible="false" data-tolerance="0">
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-popup-container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function (event, ui) {
    $("#sql").on("popupbeforeposition", popUpSql_OnBeforePosition);
});

function popUpSql_OnBeforePosition(event, ui) {
    var horizSpacing = 5;
    var vertSpacing = 5;
    var horizPaddingBorderSize = $(this).outerWidth() - $(this).width();
    var vertPaddingBorderSize = $(this).outerHeight() - $(this).height();

    $(this).css({
        left: horizSpacing,
        top: vertSpacing,
        width: window.innerWidth - (horizSpacing * 2) - horizPaddingBorderSize,
        height: window.innerHeight - (vertSpacing * 2) - vertPaddingBorderSize
    });
}
```

This code also allows you to change the horizontal and vertical spacing of the popup, letting the shadow border visible.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rosberglinhares/3yq1skzw/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This code add a new method 'setText' to the widget mobile.popup defined in jquery sources.
Use it to change the popup content. The popup will be centered on window automatically

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popup-info"  data-theme="b" class="ui-content" >
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">Fermer</a>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>    

<script>
(function($) {
    $.widget( "mobile.popup", $.mobile.popup, {
        setText: function(_text) {
            container=this.element.find('div:first');
            if(container!==undefined){
                container.html(_text);
            }else{
                this.element.html(_text);
            }
            var newX = parseInt(($(window).width()-this._ui.container.width())/2);      
            var newY = parseInt(($(window).height()-this._ui.container.height())/2);        
            this.reposition( {x:newX,y:newY,positionTo:'window'}  );
        }
    });     
})(jQuery);

$('#popup-info').popup('setText',str);
</script>
```