# Prevent to override all class of pop up in Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery mobile, Also new in jquery mobile. Right now i am implementing a full screen pop up. But when i set property for this pop up then all pop up take same property i cant override the pop up property. I have seen one link for full screen pop up. 
[How to make a Jquery mobile popup appear in full screen of device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424160/how-to-make-a-jquery-mobile-popup-appear-in-full-screen-of-device)

When i am set the class (.ui-popup-container .ui-popup). Then all popup take same property. I want to override this property for particular pop up.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/f76nD/)

```
.ui-popup-container, .ui-popup {
    height: 98%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

I want to override class for particular pop up.