# JQ UI Dialog Position Default not the same Desktop to Mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, mobile, dialog

I have a page that has table with a lot of data and in several place embedded buttons in some columns that bring up dialog boxes for the user to interact with the data on that row.

On the a desktop browser JQ UI does exactly what I want.   If the window is narrow and you have to use the scrolls bars to find the buttons (in the rightmost column), when you click on the button the dialog pops up centered in the currently viewed screen.  Here is a link to the fiddle and the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/davetoolin/c6gzx08L/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#dialog-test").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 100,
        modal: true,
        responsive: true,
        position: {
          my: "center",
          at: "center",
          of: window
        }

      });
      $(".open_dialog").click(function() {
        $("#dialog-test").dialog('open');
      })

    });

  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div style="min-width:800px">
    <table style="min-width:1350px">
      <tr>
        <td>Data Col-0 Row-0</td>
        <td>Data Col-1 Row-0</td>
        <td>Data Col-2 Row-0</td>
        <td>Data Col-3 Row-0</td>
        <td>Data Col-4 Row-0</td>
        <td>Data Col-5 Row-0</td>
        <td>Data Col-6 Row-0</td>
        <td>Data Col-7 Row-0</td>
        <td>Data Col-8 Row-0</td>
        <td>Data Col-9 Row-0</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="open_dialog" style="float:right">OPEN Dialog</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Col-0 Row-1</td>
        <td>Data Col-1 Row-1</td>
        <td>Data Col-2 Row-1</td>
        <td>Data Col-3 Row-1</td>
        <td>Data Col-4 Row-1</td>
        <td>Data Col-5 Row-1</td>
        <td>Data Col-6 Row-1</td>
        <td>Data Col-7 Row-1</td>
        <td>Data Col-8 Row-1</td>
        <td>Data Col-9 Row-1</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="open_dialog" style="float:right">OPEN Dialog</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Col-0 Row-2</td>
        <td>Data Col-1 Row-2</td>
        <td>Data Col-2 Row-2</td>
        <td>Data Col-3 Row-2</td>
        <td>Data Col-4 Row-2</td>
        <td>Data Col-5 Row-2</td>
        <td>Data Col-6 Row-2</td>
        <td>Data Col-7 Row-2</td>
        <td>Data Col-8 Row-2</td>
        <td>Data Col-9 Row-2</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="open_dialog" style="float:right">OPEN Dialog</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Col-0 Row-3</td>
        <td>Data Col-1 Row-3</td>
        <td>Data Col-2 Row-3</td>
        <td>Data Col-3 Row-3</td>
        <td>Data Col-4 Row-3</td>
        <td>Data Col-5 Row-3</td>
        <td>Data Col-6 Row-3</td>
        <td>Data Col-7 Row-3</td>
        <td>Data Col-8 Row-3</td>
        <td>Data Col-9 Row-3</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="open_dialog" style="float:right">OPEN Dialog</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Col-0 Row-4</td>
        <td>Data Col-1 Row-4</td>
        <td>Data Col-2 Row-4</td>
        <td>Data Col-3 Row-4</td>
        <td>Data Col-4 Row-4</td>
        <td>Data Col-5 Row-4</td>
        <td>Data Col-6 Row-4</td>
        <td>Data Col-7 Row-4</td>
        <td>Data Col-8 Row-4</td>
        <td>Data Col-9 Row-4</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="open_dialog" style="float:right">OPEN Dialog</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Col-0 Row-5</td>
        <td>Data Col-1 Row-5</td>
        <td>Data Col-2 Row-5</td>
        <td>Data Col-3 Row-5</td>
        <td>Data Col-4 Row-5</td>
        <td>Data Col-5 Row-5</td>
        <td>Data Col-6 Row-5</td>
        <td>Data Col-7 Row-5</td>
        <td>Data Col-8 Row-5</td>
        <td>Data Col-9 Row-5</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="open_dialog" style="float:right">OPEN Dialog</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Col-0 Row-6</td>
        <td>Data Col-1 Row-6</td>
        <td>Data Col-2 Row-6</td>
        <td>Data Col-3 Row-6</td>
        <td>Data Col-4 Row-6</td>
        <td>Data Col-5 Row-6</td>
        <td>Data Col-6 Row-6</td>
        <td>Data Col-7 Row-6</td>
        <td>Data Col-8 Row-6</td>
        <td>Data Col-9 Row-6</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="open_dialog" style="float:right">OPEN Dialog</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Col-0 Row-7</td>
        <td>Data Col-1 Row-7</td>
        <td>Data Col-2 Row-7</td>
        <td>Data Col-3 Row-7</td>
        <td>Data Col-4 Row-7</td>
        <td>Data Col-5 Row-7</td>
        <td>Data Col-6 Row-7</td>
        <td>Data Col-7 Row-7</td>
        <td>Data Col-8 Row-7</td>
        <td>Data Col-9 Row-7</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="open_dialog" style="float:right">OPEN Dialog</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Col-0 Row-8</td>
        <td>Data Col-1 Row-8</td>
        <td>Data Col-2 Row-8</td>
        <td>Data Col-3 Row-8</td>
        <td>Data Col-4 Row-8</td>
        <td>Data Col-5 Row-8</td>
        <td>Data Col-6 Row-8</td>
        <td>Data Col-7 Row-8</td>
        <td>Data Col-8 Row-8</td>
        <td>Data Col-9 Row-8</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="open_dialog" style="float:right">OPEN Dialog</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data Col-0 Row-9</td>
        <td>Data Col-1 Row-9</td>
        <td>Data Col-2 Row-9</td>
        <td>Data Col-3 Row-9</td>
        <td>Data Col-4 Row-9</td>
        <td>Data Col-5 Row-9</td>
        <td>Data Col-6 Row-9</td>
        <td>Data Col-7 Row-9</td>
        <td>Data Col-8 Row-9</td>
        <td>Data Col-9 Row-9</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="open_dialog" style="float:right">OPEN Dialog</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="dialog-test" title="test Dialog" style="display:none">This a test dialog to see in the default JQ positioning is centered in mobile devices.</div>
</body
```

On the phone,  it doesn't work that way at all.   (I haven't figure on how to do a mobile emulation using fiddle)
I swipe left to get over to see the buttons when I click on.  The screen un-swipes and moves back to the left edge of the table and shows the dialog centered on the left most data. I don't want this un-swiping behavior.

I have tried most all of the tricks, I have found in other SO's  They all work great for the desktop browser, but none affect the mobile view.
Here are some screen shots
[image: Before Click Button]
[image: After dialog open look at background we are now way left in the table.]

Thank in advance.

Twistys comment below sums up my problem perfectly.

> The dialog window is opening in the center center of the Window, or
> maybe the Document, but not the center of the Viewport area of the
> device. You want it to remain Scrolled to the right and the dialog
> should appear center in the Screen or Viewable area.

Comment: You can use the `show` path to provide just the result, and this can be used for Mobile testing: https://jsfiddle.net/davetoolin/c6gzx08L/1/show/ for example.

Comment: When I test the code using Android with Goggle Chrome, it works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ouqpvwzb/2/show

Comment: I couldn't get the show to allow me to click, but I added some screen shots.

Comment: Please describe the exact steps to take to replicate the issue. If you set the browser to use the iPhone view after navigating to the Fiddle, it may not read the right window properties. It is also good to test on a mobile device itself.

Comment: I also tested with FireFox 88 using the iPhone 6/7/8 iOS 11 Responsive Design Mode. I was unable to replicate the issue as you described it.

Comment: The screen shots I took are from a real web page not the fiddle.

Comment: This link should take you to a live page that I looked from my pixel 4a https://test.regattaman.com/includes/fixing_scripts/test_jq_dialog_mobile_centering.php

Comment: Cool, I was able to open the link and replicate the issue as you described it. The dialog window is opening in the center center of the Window, or maybe the Document, but not the center of the Viewport area of the device. You want it to remain Scrolled to the right and the dialog should appear center in the Screen or Viewable area. Will investigate.

Comment: Testing with the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ouqpvwzb/30/

Comment: Just found this SO.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424160/how-to-make-a-jquery-mobile-popup-appear-in-full-screen-of-device It might be another thing to try.
Dave

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try defining the position at the time, with `open` on the widget itself:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ouqpvwzb/49/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#dialog-test").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 100,
    modal: true,
    responsive: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).dialog("widget").position({
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: window
      });
    }
  });

  $(".open_dialog").click(function() {
    $("#dialog-test").dialog('open');
  })
});
```

I don't advise using the `event.target`. I would use `this` as it should represent the original DIV item.

You can also force it with the Document Width or Scroll Left.

```
Right: (Window Width / 2) - 50
```

If the window is 480 pixels, this could set the position from the Right 190 Pixels. That would center the dialog.

Comment: I took your JS code and put in the live page.   Still has the behavior.  I had tried most of those things in the past.  Thanks for trying.